# Running Docker Oracle Container with different databases

Tags: linux, oracle11g, docker

i want to realize the following scenario:

- create a basic Oracle XE Docker container(no database inside)
- connect this container with a database file backup container
- remove the database file container and connect to another file container

Its not very useful when i create a oracle xe container with a not exexchangeable database, because then i had 20 container, each has a size of 2,5gb.

Is there a way to do this ? In my understanding, you can link container. 
So i had to create container for each database version i have and link the oracle container with the container of the database backup file. But how i can tell docker, that i want to install the backup file from one container in the oracle container, and how can i easily exchange this?

Comment: Please, consider reading about what [topics are welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what [kind of questions should be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Your question seems to be better suited for some other Stack Exchange sites, like  [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).